# How to update the dist folder of Vue js without running npm run build a second time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I ran npm run build to create a dist folder for my Vue js application, which I then pushed to git hub. But after making changes in my codebase, I still ran npm run build which then automatically create a new dist folder and replaced the former. So how can I prevent running the build command many times and just update the dist folder directly.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't push the dist folder to github IMO

Comment: Did you mean a github-pages page? Anyway, you can specify an output directory for your npm build script, so just change that to something other than 'dist'

Answer (score 1):

You can run `vite build --watch` that will be updating constantly while updating your vue files. In `package.json` I've added a script `"updater":"vite build --watch"` in `scripts`
and to deploy it to github constantly (as git commit doesn't work with me) so I created push.js in the ./ (root) dir and used  `var ghpages = require('gh-pages');ghpages.publish('dist', function(err) {});` in push.js
and I hope this helps you and works with you too
and again in `package.json` I've added a script
`"push" : "node push.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `dist` folder for a `git repository` where u host yr deployment for the final build. Then push the dist contents to the remote repo and then next time u make a deployment then since the dist folder is initialized for `git` when u push the dist contents it then updates the remote repo contents

assuming you are in `project` folder `e.g my project`

```
cd dist
git init 
git remote add origin <remote repo URL>
git push -u origin <branch-name>
```

Then do what you do (making changes to the project and run again `npm run build`
Then push again, changes in the remote repo will be available and u can pull the new contents and deploy. Hope this helps.